# How where there different personalities if all protoss were connected by the Khala?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-series

As already can be heard in the Legacy of the Void [opening cinematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_XwzBMTJaM), Artanis defines the Khala as "The sacred union of our every thought and emotion”.

However, through the games we are lead to believe that all Protoss have different personalities, which runs contrary to have unified thoughts and emotions.

Is there a lore reason for this, how this is possible, or are there fan theories about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The union of thought and emotion doesn't mean the lack of individual thought.

If the lack of individuality was true, the Dark Templars would have not existed because they would have been unable to considering the act of separating.

It seems like you are mistaking a telepathic link between everyone to equate everyone are robots.  The Protoss aren't robots, but at the same time, they have a collective bond, while still remaining persons and individuals.

In-game explanation:  When Artanis tasked Karax with investigating the key, he complained that he was unable to share thoughts with the other phase smiths, and it is difficult to work alone.  The fact that he "feels alone" and not "sit there drooling" means they have individual thoughts, even when connected via the Khala.  The Khala seems to allow instantaneous sharing of thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Well, we do not know what would actually happen with unified thoughts and emotions, but to me, it runs contrary to individuality.

Comment: Sharing thoughts and emotions is not the same as no control over it.  If I talk to you, does your thoughts disappear from your mind?  That IS sharing a thought.

Comment: It seems "sacred union" is just defined as "chat channel for", and not "singleton instance of" :-)

Comment: well unifing thoughts and emotions can be described as sharing thoughts and emotions, you can share what you think and feel, in other languages of the video they imply the same, protoss are connected. you Reading another persons Facebook/twitter wont make you automaticaly think what he writes and feel the same whay he felt

Comment: @Xerido: Definitely not... but regretfully, hearing the same things over and over again from the people you do interact with is a problem - [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). Depending on how active the connection is, getting hammered with the same thoughts over and over again may have a similar effect. It just makes the Dark Templar's dissonance even more exception.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with this is that sharing all thoughts and emotions means there is no privacy, all know everything about each other, which doesn't seem to be a good breeding ground for individuality

Comment: It doesn't imply they are forced to connect to it all the time.  And the idea of an individual to be selected as a leader mean they have to be different in some tangible way.  Otherwise the selection of a leader is completely meaningless because the next dude will do exactly the same thing.